# Call function in stateChanged()

Tags: java, listener

I got class A which, after button is clicked:

```
if (source == buttonA){          
new classB(this);
}
```

moreover, class A has function named

```
function(int a);
```

In class B I've got

```
public class classB extends JFrame implements ChangeListener {    

    public classB(A a) {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){            
           JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
           tmp = source.getValue();                             
           a.function(tmp);         
        }
    }
}
```

But a cannot be resolved. How can I achieve that in other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `classB` to this:

```
  public class classB extends JFrame implements ChangeListener {
    private A a;

    public classB(A a) {
      this.a = a;
    }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
      JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
      int tmp = source.getValue();
      a.function(tmp);
    }
  }
```

**Explanation**

A couple of things were wrong with this class. Firstly the nested `stateChanged` function in the constructor. Taking this out, meant that `classB` needed a reference to class `A`, that's why it needed a `private A a;` field, and needed to be set in the constructor. Also, variable `tmp` was not declared, always declare a variable before using it.

using this would have worked as well:

```
int tmp;                    //<-- variable declared, you can now assign a value to it.
tmp = source.getValue();
```